# WebDriverWait.until.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located not waiting for reloaded DOM

Tags: selenium, appium, webdriverwait, python-appium

I have an app with 2 buttons. Button A takes the app to a new page with no buttons, then returns to the page with 2 buttons. My automated test is meant to click on Button A, wait while the app heads to the new pages and returns, then click on Button B.

The code:

```
    el05a = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_a"))
    )
    el05a.click()
    el05b = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_b"))
    )
    el05b.click()
```

However, I receive a StaleElementReferenceException about button B not being in DOM anymore.

Obviously, button B is not gonna be in the DOM while the app is at the new page, but why does my code not know to wait until the presence of button B is located? I thought presence_of_element_located means the code would be on hold until the element is located.

I know this could "technically" be patched with a time.sleep module but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Can you try visibility_of_element_located instead of presence_of_element_located?

Comment: It worked. Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Sure.. I will post an answer :) Glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**visibility_of_element_located**: Returns the WebElement once it is located and visible.

- An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

**presence_of_element_located**: Returns the WebElement if element is present on DOM and not even visible.

- An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

Please change it from

```
expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_a"))
```

to

```
expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_a"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your query it seems likes as your checking `presence_of_element_located` and which only check for it presence and not the visibility of the element.

**Try replacing the `presence_of_element_located` with `visibility_of_element_located`.**

---

There is difference between `visibility_of_element_located` and  `presence_of_element_located`.

**1) visibility_of_element_located**

Checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Basically it tests if the element we are looking for is present as well as visible on the page.

**2) presence_of_element_located**

Checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page.  Basically it tests if the element we are looking for is present somewhere on the page.

**Code:**

```
 el05a = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        expected_conditions. visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_a"))
    )
    el05a.click()
    el05b = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        expected_conditions. visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_button_b"))
    )
    el05b.click()
```